# R-tree() function not using any variables

Tags: r, machine-learning, decision-tree

My code,

```
tree_model<-tree(readmitted_bin~ num_medications_01,data = tree_trainData)
plot(tree_model)
```

where readmitted_bin is a factor of 0 and 1 and num_medications_01 is scaled between 0 and 1. I have included other variables that also return the following error:

```
Error in plot.tree(tree_model) : cannot plot singlenode tree
3.
stop("cannot plot singlenode tree")
2.
plot.tree(tree_model)
1.
plot(tree_model)
```

The dataframe:

n|readmitted_bin
|
num_medications_01

1   0   0.3375
2   0   0.2125
3   0   0.0875
4   1   0.2000
5   1   0.1875
6   1   0.1250

Any help is appreciated on how tree() works.

Comment: What package is `tree` from? From the rest of the context I assume it's something ML-related, but without knowing where this comes from it'll be hard to help you out.

Comment: it is from tree!

Comment: Posting the first rows of your data can help getting answers. Try copying the output of the `dput` function.

Comment: see above for sample

Comment: can you try it with larger sample size? it seems it only works with 12 or more records.

Comment: The sample size is ~90k